# System.UserManagement.initSelfRegistration and System.UserManagement.verifySelfRegistration in apex rest?

Tags: apex, customer-community, apexrest, authentication

We have a requirement where a user will be ask to register/verify on external website but we need to create a portal user for them and verify them using OTP sent in email. We know that methods like
`System.UserManagement.initSelfRegistration` and `System.UserManagement.verifySelfRegistration` work with Visualforce pages. However, we need this method to work in apexrest service. Users will be asked to register to external website, REST API will be called to initiate registration, OTP  will be sent on email. A User will enter OTP on external website and REST API will be called to verify it. Can we achieve it?

Comment: You could understand the User registration process and approach to make it work with help of this [link](https://emc.extremenetworks.com/content/oneview/docs/control/access_control/docs/portal_config/l_ov_ia_ht_oauth_salesforce.htm), altogether, you may need to post more details about implementation you have done so far, and ask about issue where you are stuck.

Comment: We want external website to use the salesforce authentication like password less login. As few pages will be on external website as well as few will be on salesforce community. For eg., A user needs to see a page which resides on external website but only if the users has portal account in salesforce community and he/she should be verified using OTP as we can log them in using password less login feature.(site.passwordlessLogin)